# Gmail and Salesforce- long delay in forwarding email

Tags: gmail, salesforce

We use Salesforce and Google Apps.
We have a Google Apps Email account that accepts an email and forwards this on to Salesforce, where Salesforce creates a case.

The last 2 fridays, we have had problems where it can take over 3 overs for an email to make its way into Salesforce.

How do I find out if the problem is with Google Mail not forwarding the email on in a timely manner, or the problem is Salesforce not processing it in a timely manner?

Anyone else ever had this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas, which you may have already tried:

1) You could check the timestamps in Gmail to see when the emails were received and then forwarded to Salesforce to see if there was a delay.

2) You could check the dates against the Salesforce system status page to see if there were any reported issues: http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/

3) Same for the Google Apps status page: http://www.google.com/appsstatus

4) Check to see if there were any other delays in Salesforce or concurrent batch jobs that might have caused the delay.

5) Submit a support request to Salesforce to inquire.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Are you using Salesforce Email to Case?  Here's someone posting a similar question: https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=a1X30000000IGwWEAW.  It seems that at the time that both problems were a temporary outage on the part of Salesforce.  Also, are you using any apps to integrate Gmail and Salesforce? Because apps like The Scoop Composer allow you to forward emails and create cases right away. http://www.cloudgizmos.com/salesforce-gmail-integration.  Hope this helps!